# Self dual electromagnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism

Has anyone developed (or is working on) a self-dual EM field in toroidal coordinates? If so, please reference.
Self dual refers basically to the EM field tensor but the practical meaning is that the electric vector at a every point is parallel to the magnetic vector at that point, which implies that the Poynting  vector is identically zero at every point.  There is a relativistic version of this but I am speaking in a 3D classical mode.
One can think of this with a time varying (usually exponential) vector attached or not, but the timeless version draws attention to the essential geometric aspect of the question.  In this case the question reduces to  finding vector field F such that curl(F) = F. 
Toroidal coordinates are explained in Morse and Feshbach: "Methods of Theoretical Physics ", Part I, Chap. 1.3 and on pages 555 and 666.  They also explain (in section 5.1 to page 497), how the use of curvilinear coordinates is a guess that the solution will have integral lines along those coordinate lines and thus have a simple expression in that system. A search on self dual EM fields gives several answers but I have yet to find one in toroidal coordinates.

For a given PDE, The word 'developing' is used to mean the indefinite process of finding the right mix of boundary conditions and mathematically simple expressions which satisfy the given equation. As far as I know there is no explicit method of finding solutions of PDE's of this complexity.  In this case, I have convinced myself that there is a formal solution (in known functions and operators) with some of the right boundary values, etc., but I have not found a simple method of expression which shows the general geometric form of the solution or facilitates computation.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This question is a little vague as posed - it would help if you can clarify exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: A bit more context and background would improve this question. What are "toroidal" coordinates, and what do you mean by "developing" a self-dual EM field?

Comment: Okay, so your notion of duality is the standard one. There is already a large body of literature on electromagnetic duality, so what are you looking for? Just anything that uses toroidal coordinates and electromagnetic duality? Googling gives me e.g. [this paper by Verlinde](http://cds.cern.ch/record/282637/files/9506011.pdf)